# OpenCV Hu moments extraction

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm trying to make a fire detection using Machine learning. My features are mean RGB, variance RGB, and Hu moments.
So what I'm doing right now is I first segment an image based  [on this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.253.818&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

According to the paper I use the rules

```
r > g && g > b
r > 190 && g > 100 && b < 140
```

here is the result of my color segmentation for the negative and positive images

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

The pictures on the right are now in

```
vector<Mat> processedImage
```

After that I get the hu moments of each picture by converting it into gray scale and blurring it.

```
cvtColor(processedImage[x], gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(gray_image, gray_image, Size(3, 3));
Canny(gray_image, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
cv::Moments mom = cv::moments(contours[0]);
cv::HuMoments(mom, hu); // now in hu are your 7 Hu-Moments
```

Now I am stuck I'm not sure if my images are okay to obtain useful hu moments because the negative images are so scattered.
Am I on the right track with regards to Hu moments extraction? Will I do the same on testing where I do color segmentation before extracting hu moments?

Comment: I guess I would start by using some morphological operators (erosion/ dilation) to eliminate holes/noise. But why would you use Hu moments? And do you have a training set?

Comment: I used Hu moments because the paper "Fire flame detection in video sequences using multi-stage pattern recognition techniques" said "Hu invariant moments (Hu 1962) are very effective for the description of the fire regions because they clearly distinguish between moving fire and non-fire regions.
"

Comment: yes I have a training set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should follow these steps (Code in Python):

1.Create a binary image by iterating through the original. If a pixel is identified as fire will be turned to white otherwise to black (Be careful if you are using BRG or RGB. OpenCV read images in BRG so you need to convert first):

```
rows,cols = im2.shape[:2]
for i in xrange(rows):
    for j in xrange(cols):
    if im2[i,j,0]>im2[i,j,1] and im2[i,j,1]>im2[i,j,2] and im2[i,j,0]>190 and im2[i,j,1] > 100 and im2[i,j,2] <140:
        im2[i,j,:]=255
    else:
        im2[i,j,:]=0
```

Result:

[image]

2.Use morphological operators and blurring to reduce noise/small contours.

```
# Convert to greyscale-monochromatic
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) 
#Apply Gaussian Blur 
blur= cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)

# Threshold again since after gaussian blur the image is no longer binary
(thresh, bw_image) = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY| cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
# Difine Kernel Size and apply erosion filter
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(7,7))  
dilated=cv2.dilate(bw_image,element) 
eroded=cv2.erode(dilated,element)
```

[image]

3.Afterwards, you can detect contours using the cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL flag, so you can ignore all inner contours (you are interested only in the outer contours of the fire regions). Also you  can retain only the contours whose are is bigger than e.g. 500px or just choose the bigger one if you know there is only one "fire".

```
 g, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(eroded,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours_retain=[]
for cnt in contours:
    if  cv2.contourArea(cnt)>500: 
        contours_retain.append(cnt)

cv2.drawContours(im_cp,contours_retain,-1,(255,0,255),3)
```

Here is the fire region:

[image]

4.Finally calculate your Hu moments

```
 for cnt in contours_retain:
    print cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(cnt)).flatten()
```

I hope this helps! Sorry I am not familiar with C++!

Comment: So what youre saying is I wont use canny anymore?  what will be my 1st parameter in findContours?

Comment: this will be my new findcontours?? findContours(processedImage[x], contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

Comment: got an error "FindContours support only 8uc1 and 32sc1 images"

Comment: Are you using a monochrome image? Or does it have more than one channels?

Comment: Your first parameter will be a binary image where the fire pixels will be white and everything else black. The image should have only one channel. I suggest that some pre-processing will be useful. I have some code using openCV but in python. I could add it to my answer - could you convert it then to C++?

Comment: what I did on segmentation was if(fire) all 3 channels = 255 so I guess its 3 channels.. sure maybe I can understand

Comment: Is there any way in opencv for the "500" to become dynamic? I mean how do I choose which contour is the biggest if for example I have 1000 pictures?

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the Hu moments I need :))